# Rename [luis] to [azure-language-understanding]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Currently [luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luis) is used for azure language understanding. However, the Microsoft standard for azure related tags is using the `[azure-]` prefix, which Microsoft Q&A also uses. My suggestion, therefore, is to change the name of [luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luis) to [azure-language-understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-language-understanding).

Link for reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-language-understanding.html

Comment: Once renamed should it have a synonym azure-luis?  Seems like that's how it's known, at least to some.

Comment: As of the recent proposal [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931), the [luis.ai] tag has also been merged into and made a synonym of the [azure-language-understanding] tag.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done easily, however there's a small problem in here. [luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luis) is a sponsored tag, and therefore the tag sponsorship would also need to be moved to the new tag, [azure-language-understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-language-understanding) post rename. For this, we would need to contact a Community Manager.

Additionally, as Trevor mentioned, we need to add [azure-luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-luis) as a synonym, in order to add to the visibility of the tag, which I can do as a moderator.

I'll ping a CM, and inform them about this request.

Answer (score 6):

The current sponsorship is running till the 24th of October. Given that moving the icon would require quite a bit of operational work on the backend, I'd like to propose to wait till that moment and then change the tag name.

*Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Stack, working as a Product Manager in the Advertising team*