# Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, collectives

Last month [we announced](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/01/17/microsoft-azure-joins-collectives-on-stack-overflow/) the launch of the [Microsoft Azure Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure).

Microsoft Azure's engineers have been assessing the Azure-related tags on Stack Overflow that are not yet part of the Collective, and Azure-related tags that might benefit from being merged.

Community Managers will execute these changes, so there will be no work needed from the community.

**To those who are active in these tags: Do you have any concerns? Are there any reasons these changes should not be made?** Discussion will be open for about two weeks unless there is a need to extend that, and we’ll make the updates after it concludes. The proposed updates are below.

### Proposed tag renames for standardization:

| Current name | Proposed name |
| --- | --- |
| [qnamaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qnamaker) | azure-qna-maker |
| [video-indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-indexer) | azure-video-indexer |
| [adal-deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adal-deprecation) | azure-ad-adal-deprecation |
| [msal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msal) | azure-ad-msal |

After the rename, these tags would be added to the Collective.

### Proposed tag merges:

| Target | Synonym(s) |
| --- | --- |
| [azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) | [azure-sql-server-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-server-managed-instance) |
| [azure-machine-learning-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-service) | [azure-machine-learning-workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-workbench) [azure-machine-learning-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-machine-learning-studio) |
| [azure-eventhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-eventhub) | [azure-eventhub-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-eventhub-capture) |
| [azure-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-synapse) | [azure-sql-pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-pool) [azure-sqldw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sqldw) [azure-sql-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-data-warehouse)* |
| [azure-cognitive-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cognitive-services) | [microsoft-cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-cognitive) ^ |
| [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) | [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2) [azure-data-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-flow) [azure-integration-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-integration-runtime) [azure-data-factory-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-pipeline) [copy-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy-activity)** |
| [azure-language-understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-language-understanding) | [luis.ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luis.ai) ** |
| [azure-rm-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-rm-template) (this would be a new tag) | [azure-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-template) [arm-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm-template)** |
| [azure-app-registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-app-registration) | [app-registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-registration)** |

*There is a open discussion related to three of these tags [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418953/make-azure-sqldw-a-synonym-of-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

^The merge proposed here was [also suggested in 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385333/make-microsoft-cognitive-synonym-of-azure-cognitive-services)

**This tag is not currently part of the Microsoft Azure Collective

Several of these proposed merges have been pending approval since 2021.

## Update: March 13

The following changes have been made to the proposals above based on the answers and comments on this post.

- Removed proposal to synonymize [azure-sql-server-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-server-managed-instance) and [azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) to [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database)
- Added proposal to synonymize [azure-sql-server-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-server-managed-instance) and [azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) (with feedback solicited on which should be the target)
- Removed proposal to synonymize a number of `azure-cosmosdb` tags to [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb)
- Added [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2) into the list of tags we propose to merge into [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory)
- Removed the proposal to rename [azure-billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-billing) to `azure-cost-management`
- Removed the proposal to rename [windows-virtual-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-virtual-desktop) to `azure-virtual-desktop`
- Removed the proposal to rename [bing-custom-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-custom-search) to `azure-bing-custom-search`
- Removed proposal to synonymize [azure-vm-role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm-role) to [azure-virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-virtual-machine)

**Thanks to all who gave feedback on the initial proposals. This post will remain open to further feedback until Monday March 20.**

Comment: Why do we even have [tag:azure-billing]? Just burninate it quickly

Comment: [tag:windows-virtual-desktop] doesn't seem to be about azure. I think it needs burnination too.

Comment: @Dharman Agreed. Billing problems are a customer support problem

Comment: I seriously doubt whether many of these tags are on-topic here. Some questions are asking about creating accounts, some about using some kind of cloud tool, etc. Many do not contain code or any mention that they are using this tool in a programming context.

Comment: @Dharman I also had the same concern regarding [tag:windows-virtual-desktop], but apparently [Azure has the same named feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-virtual-desktop%5D+azure+is%3Aq). Probably need clean-up before either renaming it or creating it as a new tag. There's also [tag:wvd] referring to [tag:windows-virtual-desktop]

Comment: Some of the [most popular younger questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-for-newer-questions) are about problems with GitHub accounts. That is out of more than 3,000,000 younger questions. (There are also many duplicates.). [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68775869): #3 with about 2,500 views per days on average over its lifetime (1.5 years).

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Especially since there is a dedicated tag for the billing API

Comment: Could you ask those engineers to create some tag wikis for all these tags, please?

Comment: It's been about *4 weeks* since this post was made and no changes have been done; has it been a little forgotten about?

Comment: @Larnu Nope, in fact I am going to post an update later today.

Comment: @Dharman regarding [tag:azure-billing], the proposed rename was removed from the post. As part of a burnination process for that tag, we'd propose to make sure on-topic questions are tagged/retagged with either [tag:azure-billing-api] or a new tag `azure-cost-management` for the service of that name. Let us know if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: @Dharman (and Andrew T) regarding [tag:windows-virtual-desktop], indeed some questions are not Azure-related. As part of a burnination process for that tag and [tag:wvd], we'd propose to make sure on-topic Azure-related questions are tagged with a new tag `azure-virtual-desktop`. Let us know if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: @Bergi We have passed along that suggestion

Comment: The tag changes in the revised proposal have now been completed.

Answer (score 36):

I disagree with the proposal to make [azure-sql-server-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-server-managed-instance) and [azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) a synonym of [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database). These are 2 distinct products according to the Documentation, [What is Azure SQL Managed Instance?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview?view=azuresql) vs [What is [Azure] SQL Database?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview?view=azuresql), and they actually have a different variety of [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison?view=azuresql#features-of-sql-database-and-sql-managed-instance).

Making these synonyms would make things harder for those of us active in the tags, as Azure SQL Databases are contained databases, which comes with a wealth of caveats, that a Managed instance would not have (such as the ability to use cross-database queries).

Due to the feature support alone, these should not be synonyms as it makes it far easier to tell when a user is trying to do something that isn't supported in the product they are using. The fact that the documentation explicitly defines them as different products cements that they should not be the same.

*Note that I do think [azure-sql-server-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-server-managed-instance) and [azure-sql-managed-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-managed-instance) should be synonyms.*

Comment: The proposal has been updated to reflect these changes you suggested

Answer (score 26):

Well... I understand that Microsoft is a probably well paying customer for you. I really understand it.

But... what I see on the list, that the Microsoft wants you to advertize the "Azure" keyword, that is important for them, and not the quality of information maintained by you.

Actually, most of the technologies have little to do the Azure, except that they are connected with it (or usable as a service in it).

If they asked you and do not pay *really* well, my suggestion would be to reject their whole proposal as it is.

Comment: This should be enough proof of how much money Microsoft brings them https://resources.stackoverflow.co/topic/client-stories/microsoft-case-study

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ok but if they follow everything what they say, the SO will become a new microsoft support. And on the ruins, some new will appear. Even if the MS pays them a lot, did not paid for that.

Answer (score 22):

"azure-bing-custom-search" seems like pretty arbitrary keyword stuffing, and makes me question how anyone "assessing tags" would come to suggest it.

I searched for "azure bing custom search" on DuckDuckGo, and landed on [a page with this message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/overview):

> On October 30, 2020, the Bing Search APIs moved from Cognitive Services to Bing Search Services. This documentation is provided for reference only. For updated documentation, see [the Bing search API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/).

The newer documentation linked to does not appear to mention the brand "Azure" anywhere.

Meanwhile, [the tag currently features on 11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-custom-search), only two of which have positive scores (one scores 3, one 1, six 0, and three -1).

Most also feature some combination of [bing-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-search) (which has 65 questions) and/or [bing-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-api) (which has 730 questions), neither are listed as needing to be burdened with the "azure-" prefix.

Comment: This is the service it's referencing:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That is the index above the page I found on DuckDuckGo. Click any link on that page, and you'll see the banner I quoted saying that this service has moved away from "Cognitive Services". If its new home under "Bing Search Services" is considered part of "Azure", the current documentation does a really good job of hiding that.

Comment: It's complicated.  That's kind of both the Bing API under Bing, but billed through Azure_and_ and Azure service called Azure Bing Search, which is part of Azure Cognitive Services.  My point is that the Azure tag prefix isn't _entirely_ redundant.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The message I quoted seems entirely clear to me that it is **no longer** part of Azure Cognitive Services. [This billing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/) has slightly different wording, saying it moved to "new surface area under Microsoft.com" (note, *not* "within Azure"); it also gives a maximum support period of October this year. MS often reuse brands in unhelpful ways (e.g. Azure Data Studio, elsewhere on this page), but in this case "Azure" seems to have consistently been *removed* from the brand.

Comment: We removed the proposal to rename [tag:bing-custom-search] and will not add that tag to the collective.

Answer (score 18):

I realise that this post is asking about the tags listed for merged/synonymising, however, it would also be "nice" if [azure-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-studio) (ADS) could be removed from the collective.

Although, yes, it has "Azure" in its name, that is really all the application has in common with Azure. ADS is a reskinned version of VSCode that is specifically designed for dealing with DBMS, such as Microsoft SQL Server. Yes it can connect to Azure services as well, but so too can SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which Microsoft frequently seem to badge that ADS is "replacing".

Having ADS in the collective really doesn't make any sense, as it's not about Azure and could be *completely* void of any cloud based technology; I for example daily drive ADS because SSMS isn't available on anything other than Windows and thus I have to use ADS instead even though I'm using on-premises instances. Having ADS be part of the collective because of its "name only" isn't a good reason. If it's based on what it can do, then [vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode), [ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) and even [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) should all be part of the collective because you can do stuff with Azure using them as well (it is *not* my opinion those tags should be added).

So can we please remove [azure-data-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-studio) from the collective? If the question is about a cloud-based (R)DBMS, then the question will also be tagged with the appropriate one, such as [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database), [azure-synapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-synapse), or [azure-sql-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-edge).

Answer (score 5):

I occasionally answer azure-cosmosdb questions and I find the current set of tags useful.

Probably the [azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi) should get synomized to [azure-cosmosdb-nosqlapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-nosqlapi) as somewhat annoyingly the API was rebranded to that some time ago.

Apart from that though I think the current set of sub tags provide a useful level of categorisation and mandatory information to know (the different APIs have entirely different programmability interfaces and often different features available) as well as allowing me to quickly filter out questions that I am unlikely to be able to answer

(I personally am only going to be likely to look at [azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi), [azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi), [azure-cosmosdb-changefeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb-changefeed) tags).

Maybe an Azure Engineer on the Cosmos team will be equally well versed in all of the APIs but for general users it is entirely possible to just have knowledge in (say) the MongoDB API and know nothing about Gremlin.

Comment: Agreed. The individual API tags are valuable, as many of the questions have specific ways of answering, based on the API in use. Also, there are Cosmos DB questions unrelated to a specific API (such as ones around terraform scripts, or programmatically configuring a Cosmos DB instance).

Comment: The proposal above has been updated and no longer includes any changes to the existing cosmosdb tags, keeping the specific tags for each API

Answer (score 5):

Regarding VMs: [azure-virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-virtual-machine) represents questions related to today's current VM offerings in Azure, while [azure-vm-role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm-role) is about a really old, now-deprecated mechanism for uploading and instantiating custom VM images. These should not be synonyms.

I can see where there might be an assumption where these are synonymous: several questions over the past several years have been mis-tagged with [azure-vm-role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm-role) (I just removed a few from the recent 3 years).

The only valid synonym in use right now is [azure-vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm) (and should remain so).

I would suggest leaving [azure-vm-role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-vm-role) as a standalone tag, but omit it from the Collective.

Comment: We removed the proposal to synonymize [tag:azure-vm-role] to [tag:azure-virtual-machine], and we will remove [tag:azure-vm-role] from the collective

Answer (score 4):

May I ask about the tag [azure-data-factory-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory-2)? Should we also merge it into [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory)?

Here is a [very elementary sql](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1710247) I write in SEDE. I am trying to count how many questions are related to ADF v1 only.

The result:

|  | count |
| --- | --- |
| ADF v1 questions | 96 |
| all ADF questions | 4802 |

It is just around 2% of the ADF questions that explicitly refer to ADF v1.

In addition, from this [Microsoft page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/migrate-your-azure-data-factory-version-1-to-2-service/),

> After 31 August 2023, Azure Data Factory version 1 will not be supported.

I am not an expert in ADF so I don't quite know how ADF v2, as the latest version of ADF, differentiates from ADF v1. I hope experts in ADF can provide valuable insight into this.

So, is the tag [azure-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-factory) alone can cover questions for all ADF versions? Can we just keep 1 tag for ADF?

Comment: As a note, it looks like there's already a 2020 proposal here (from an Azure engineer) about merging those tags as you suggest: [Request to merge tags \[azure-data-factory-2\] with \[azure-data-factory\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401184/1478931). ...I also found this 2018 proposal from another user to just rename the \[azure-data-factory\] tag to \[azure-data-factory-v1\] instead: [When a technology has significant changes should the tag be renamed? Azure-data-factory in this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371914/1478931)

Comment: The proposal for [tag:azure-data-factory] has been updated to include the additional tag [tag:azure-data-factory-2]