# How to properly handle Azure related questions

Tags: discussion, scope, collectives

For several weeks now I have seen a lot of questions related to Azure, but I struggle to see how they are on-topic for Stack Overflow. Some examples:

- [Azure Storage Account mounted in AKS loses visibility into files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75813048/azure-storage-account-mounted-in-aks-loses-visibility-into-files)
- [Problem with binding pvc with static pv in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75799784/problem-with-binding-pvc-with-static-pv-in-kubernetes)
- [Connect private Azure AKS Cluster with an Virtual Machine in different VNETs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75753386/connect-private-azure-aks-cluster-with-an-virtual-machine-in-different-vnets)

Some more questions where I would doubt the programming-related focus could be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-billing

---

Are these kind of questions now on-topic, as there is even a Collective, inviting users to ask such questions on SO?

Comment: "as there is even a Collective" - collectives have no say in what's on-topic

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine but having one with (from my POV) a lot of off-topic questions looks like it should't have been created in the first place

Comment: Various "tools" have blurred the lines of what is and isn't programming, Azure and AWS in particular.

Comment: Collectives are a business decision mods and the community have exactly 0 say in. The fact that a collective seems to encourage more off-topic questions because of its perceived closer association to some organisation is a side-effect we now get to live with.

Comment: Just judge each question on it's own merit, just like you normally would. If it's not on-topic then vote to close it; that it's part of a collective is irrelevant.

Comment: As an example, in a recent [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/2029983) about the Microsoft Collection, they (Microsoft) suggested that [[tag:azure-billing]] be renamed to  [[tag:azure-cost-management]]; the real fact of the matter is that billing is *completely* off-topic for [so], and not one staff member that reviewed their request seemed to think about that.

Comment: As an example... billing management does often involve *some* programming. The programming bits certainly are on topic on SO, but the billing part is not. Would, then, a question about obtaining billing info be on topic, given that it *can* be solved through the CLI? Where does billing stop and programming begin? Would a question about how much something costs or controlling costs of an action be on topic, given the action is through the CLI, programatically?

Comment: @ThomA - "If it's not on-topic then vote to close it; that it's part of a collective is irrelevant" This is exactly what should happen.

In the post you reference, the rename was removed from the proposal based on community response, and the suggestion is now to burninate azure-billing and retag on-topic questions with tags that are more clearly connected to the  programming aspects that Kevin mentioned.

The collective is meant to bring focus on the subject area, and that post is part of working with the community on tag cleanup and optimization.

Comment: Yes, it was actually really good to see that community feedback was taken onboard and even caused the planned implementation to be different to what Microsoft had proposed, @Berthold . It was more of a "shame" that some things got to the post at all, like that [[tag:azure-billing]] should be renamed (rather than burninated).

Comment: @ThomA Certainly if the proposal had been to rename a tag *to* "azure-billing", that's something we would have flagged before bringing the proposal to the community. But given that the tag existed already and the proposal was to rename it to something that matched the name of one of their products, it seemed like a valid proposal. And, as it turns out, there is some nuance there in terms of being on-topic. The domain experts are in the community and the purpose of the post was to bring the proposals to all of you. From my perspective it has worked as intended but feedback is welcome as always.

Comment: I assumed you meant the product Azure Cosmos, but it seems like you actually just mean cosmos in a more general term (e.g. "all Azure products"). I've reverted that part of my edit but please specify so I am sure what you mean, so that I can help answer. We can in part blame Azure for creating a product named Azure Cosmos...

Comment: "I assumed you meant the product Azure Cosmos" - no, I haven't head of any such product. In german language (my mother-tongue), a "cosmos" might mean a whole ecosystem of products, and that's what I've meant